# Is it possible to use LinqPad with a code-first model

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, linqpad

In the past It's been easy to set a connection in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) to a custom assembly that had EF model.  Linqpad looks for a that is based on `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext` which doesn't exist

How (if at all) does one make their model assembly compatible with LinqPad.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now, LINQPad does not support the EF CTP's code-first: there's a feature request [here](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/743276-add-entity-framework-support-for-code-first?ref=title).

It's almost certain that support will be added in the future - if this EF feature makes it past CTP (and maybe sooner with sufficient demand).

**Edit**: LINQPad [now supports code-first](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) with EF 4.1.