# Can I use CTP5 DBContext with LINQPad?

Tags: entity-framework-ctp5, linqpad

As you can see on title, I would say if I can use LinqPad with CTP5 DBContext. I see the guide on http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx to link LinqPad with my EF model, but I receive the message

> There are no typed based on 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' in that assembly.

Obviously I'm using the last release of the product. I also see this section http://www.linqpad.net/extensibility.aspx, in case should write myself the driver ? (...I'm not telling I'm capable of :) )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469896/is-it-possible-to-use-linqpad-with-a-code-first-model).

Expect to see support for this soon, though!

Comment: Ok, so it's not yet possible. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works... you just need to connect using the Entity Framework driver and if you develop in any of technologies that uses dbcontext (includes code first, model first and data base first but is lighter than objectcontext), you can use the list below. But for that case you need to connect using poco